# Add mutiple rows to child table usnig trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, triggers, entity-framework-5

**I have two tables:**

One is "**Requisitions**":(Parent Table)

```
RequisitionId          int
RequisitionNumber      varchar(20)
RequisitionBy          varchar(100)
ReceivedByDate         datetime 
Remarks                varchar(300)
ApprovedStatus         varchar(20)
ApprovedDate           datetime
```

Other one is "**RequisitionDetails**": (Child table)

```
RequisitionDetailId    int
RequisitionId          int
ProductId              int
UnitConversionId       int
Quantity               decimal(18, 2)
```

Here I want to write a trigger for insert of "**Requisitions**" table where I want to write query to insert multiple rows for "**RequisitionDetails**". It's like for one row insertion in "**Requisition**" table multiple row will automatically be inserted to "**RequisitionDetails**" table by the trigger. Need help to do this.

Comment: What do you want to insert into RequisitionDetails? How will the trigger know what the values should be?

Comment: I am really new in trigger.Is this possible to pass the data for "RequisitionDetails" by an array, every row of the array will contain the data of one row for "RequisitionDetails". Or any other ways?

Comment: you can do trigger after insert - you'll have access to that last inserted row - all the info from table "Requisitions" that you just inserted. So ONE insert could create ONE entry in  "RequisitionDetails" table (that's if you have Quantity in the Parent table...)